# VSCode run produces ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import my module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a project folder that has a module called 'src' containing my code. Within 'src', there is another module called 'crawlers' which has python code in it. In one of the files stored in the 'crawlers' folder, I call an import from the 'src' folder to get variables from its **init**.py file.
The structure is like this

```
└───src  (this is a module)
    ├───crawlers  (this is a module)
         |----- code.py
    ├───datafiles
    ├───models
    └───utils
```

in the code.py file I have

```
import json
from src import variable1, variable 2
```

When the code runs in vscode, I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Code files/tech projects/tree_courses_scraper/src/crawlers/course_grab.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src import umanitoba_calendar, umanitoba_codes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I have been using pycharm community for a while and I never got this problem.

Comment: Since a module is just a .py script (not a folder), it's unclear what the indentation shown in your graph means.

Comment: @martineau the 'src' is a module folder with an __init__.py file. 'crawlers' is also another module which has a python file called code.py

Comment: There's no such thing as a "module folder". Perhaps you mean a package folder.

Comment: I don't see where the `code.py` file relates to the error you're showing us.  The error indicates that the problem is in the file `course_grab.py`.  Is the `src` directory in your `sys.path`? Does the `src` directory include an \_\_init\_\_.py file?  Where are `umanitoba_calendar` and `umanitoba_codes` defined?  Are those the names of files or directories not shown?  None of what I see suggests that the code line in question should work.